# Is it possible to execute a jar within an Applet?

Tags: java, jar, applet, classpath

Is it possible to start/run/execute a jar within an Applet? If it is possible, how can I do this?

Comment: this may help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

Comment: Thats a different topic. I don't want to just start an applet, or pack a applet as jar. I really want a Applet that start another jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ASSUME that you could ask this as well:

- "Can a Applet start a Java class that was initialy not available in the Applets classpath?"

  => I would say no. Hence there are possibillities using Java the Applets security policys will deny required actions to do so (e.g. download/ store/ manipulate CP, call Jar in  the context of the executing client).

So the only way i see is to have a **signed Applet that is allowed to operate on the file system** and thus will be able to download a remote Jar and start it.

Comment: I think you are right. I think the way you describe with signing, downloading and then starting is the way to go. Do you maybe have example code of that for me?

Comment: I already thought about this solution but I was not sure how to do it exactly. I will later use a offical signed Applet of course. Do you maybe have an example or sample code of how to do it then? Can I run "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar my_app.jar");" with a signed Applet? I already tried it on my local computer with adding this page to the sitelist but it did not execute this command. Is it because it is not signed?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answere. I solved the problem and got the jar to run in a applet, great!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible (but not simple).

It would require a signed and trusted applet with a custom security manager to handle the security for the loaded archives.  The steps would be along these lines.

- Set the custom security manager.
- Establish an URL to the Jar.
- Establish an `URLClassLoader` for the URL.
- Load the class and instantiate it.
- Call the `main(String[])` method.